# Javascript - Nodejs Switch Global Variable Not Changing

Tags: javascript, node.js, switch-statement

I'm trying to pass an object located in my module file, `query-type.js`, to a global variable (`app.js`) based on the string passed to my switch statement, but for some reason I can't seem to get the value set to my global `params` despite the console logs in my cases correctly outputting the `params` object. My `console.log(params)` is running for both cases, but the global scope `console.log('These are the params ' + params);` is not even appearing. Any thoughts as to why this behavior is happening?

**Global JS file (Switch and global variable):**

```
function keywordQuery(auth) {

    var authSheets = auth;

    var siteUrl = encodeURIComponent('http://www.test-site.com/');

    var params;

    switch(process.argv[2]){
      case "allTrafficQuery":
        params = webmasterQuery.allTrafficQuery(auth, siteUrl);
        return console.log(params);
        break;
      case "usaTrafficQuery":
        params = webmasterQuery.usaTrafficQuery(auth, siteUrl);
        return console.log(params);
        break;
      default:
        params = ("Error");
    }    

    console.log('These are the params ' + params);
  }
```

**Module File:**

```
module.exports = {

    allTrafficQuery: function(authToken, siteUrlEncoded){
        var allTraffic = {
            auth: authToken,
            siteUrl: siteUrlEncoded,
            resource: {
                'dimensions': ['query']
            }
        }
        return allTraffic;
    },

    usaTrafficQuery: function(authToken, siteUrlEncoded){
        var usaTraffic = {
            auth: authToken,
            siteUrl: siteUrlEncoded,
            resource: {
                'dimensions': ['query'],
                'dimensionFilterGroups': [{
                  'filters': [{
                    'dimension': 'country',
                    'operator': 'equals',
                    'expression': 'USA'
                  }]
                }]
            }
        }
        return usaTraffic;
    }

};
```

Comment: Well, where are you calling `keywordQuery()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within your `switch` statement cases you are returning out of the function.

See here:

```
case "usaTrafficQuery":
    params = webmasterQuery.usaTrafficQuery(auth, siteUrl);
    return console.log(params); // This ends the function execution
    break;
```

So the logic after the switch statement (i.e. the `console.log` that you are inquiring about) doesn't get executed. It should work as you expect if it falls in the `default` case though (since it doesn't have a `return`).

Comment: simple fix to a misunderstanding of using the switch and return scope. Thank you! :)